# How to implement a text file in content (XNA)

Tags: c#, text, xna

I am building a game which loads its map from a text file.

While creating the parts that handle maps, I simply kept the text file in the content folder and fetched it by its Windows filepath. This won't work for proper deployment (or even running the game from different drives) because it requires that the filepath be exactly the same.

I looked around for a way to include the text file the same way I would a Texture2D, but I cannot find any class that allows me to use it. Some answers to other questions suggested that I just use the text file from my content folder? How would I do that? My program's name is IslandQuest (placeholder; it doesn't even involve an island) so would I place the text file in the IslandQuestContent folder generated by XNA Studio? How would I access it from there such that its filepath doesn't depend on the drive configuration of a computer?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing a while ago... I'd love to see what the answer is!

Comment: Let me load up an old xna file, 1 sec, pretty sure the answer lies in the properties of the file

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the best way to do this but just looked back at what I did in my first year at university with XNA,

I added my txt file to the contents folder. Then in the properties for the file (select it in the solution explorer and view properties window) there should be "Copy to Output Directory", make sure this is copy if newer.

Then its just a case of

```
string.Format("Content/{0}.txt", filename)
```

I do think this can be improved perhaps by the following but it is untested

```
Path.Combine(Content,filename +".txt");
```

Comment: Note: In my case, the game targeted Xbox, there are also options in the **Build Action** that can be explored

Comment: How would I use it after string.Format()?
At the moment, I'm using File.ReadAllLines() to read it into a String array, but I am of the impression that this is only for accessing an external file?

Comment: Also, it throws this error on compile: "Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "layout.txt". There are no importers which handle this file type. Specify the importer that handles this file type in your project." I looked at importers a bit earlier, but had no success.

Comment: Change the Build Action to "None". You can use File.ReadAllLines(string.Format("Content/{0}.txt", filename) to get the contents of your files. This will work in Xbox and Windows at least

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was reading XML file files from a data folder in my main project.

So under my project in Solution explore I had this set up:

```
WindowsPhoneGame1
  ...
  data/
    content.xml
  Game1.cs
  Program.cs
  etc...
```

Where properties for content.xml were Build Action: **Content** and Copy to Output Directory: **Copy always**

In the class that read the file I used [TitleContainer.OpenStream Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.titlecontainer.openstream.aspx) which according to the docs:

> Returns a stream to an existing file in the default title storage
>   location. .... The stream returned is read-only. The file to be read must already exist, or this method will fail.

My example code

```
//open stream
Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("data/content.xml");
//do something with it...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a "Content" folder in your main project.
2. Put the files that cannot be put in the Content project in there.
3. Be sure to set all your content Build actions to Content and Copy Always.

The Content folder from your main project and the content in the content project will end up in the same folder when built.

The file path would still be "Content/file.ext" or whatever.